# What does Cyrus reconstruct do?

Tags: imap, mailbox, cyrus

I have a cyrus-imapd server running for last five years. The **cyrus-imapd version is 2.2**. Now I have set up a new mailbox server with **cyrus-imapd version 2.3**. I need to migrate all mailboxes to this new server. As far as I know I should follow either of the following two methods.

1. Use `imapsync` to transfer mailboxes
2. `rsync` all mailboxes to new server and then `reconstruct` all of them on new server

I do not want to setup `imapsync` so `rsync` followed by `reconstruct` remains.

But I tried moving random five mailboxes to new server without following `reconstruct`. I did following.

1. `rsync` mailboxes to new server
2. copied `mailbox-name.seen` and `mailbox-name.sub` from `/var/lib/imap/` to new server

And I am able to access those mailboxes without any problem on new server. So can I move mailboxes and corresponding .seen and .sub files directly to new server without following `reconstruct`? and what exactly `reconstruct` do?

**Note**: I am not using any kind of quota on cyrus mailboxes so I don't want any quota figures.

Answer (score 3):

`reconstruct` reconstructs cyrus' indexes. While they may survive a move from one machine to another, nothing guarantees that they will. Reconstruct is also idempotent, non-destructive and non-intrusive, so you can safely run it on migrated mailboxes.

Comment: thanks, should I keep cyrus-imapd down during reconstruct?

Comment: No, that's not necessary.