# Reconstructing cyrus mailboxes with sub-folders

Tags: email, email-server, rsync, imap, cyrus

I have a mail server which runs Cyrus-imapd and postfix. I have another server which is to be the backup mail server. I have rsynced one mailbox from the primary server to the backup server to test. As mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/453999/what-does-cyrus-reconstruct-do), I first rsynced one test mailbox and then copied over it's .seen and .sub files from /var/lib/imap/user/t/testuser  over to the same location on the backup server.

Once this is done, I get all the mails in the inbox as is. But there are no sub-folders created and hence, I cannot see the mails in them. On checking the mailbox location for that mailbox, I find that the subfolders have been copied during the rsync processs. I ran `reconstruct` but to no avail.

Next I manually created one sub-folder (which had the same name as on the original mailbox) for this mailbox and then ran `reconstruct`. I was then able to see those mails under that sub-folder.

How do I sync the mail boxes such that I don't have to manually create the sub-folders for each user in order to see the mails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `reconstruct -rf user/testuser` or so -- the `-f` makes reconstruct examine the directories for `cyrus.*` datafiles and if it finds them, it will add those directories as sub-folders.

Comment: Ok. I ran `reconstruct -rf user/testuser` and it created the sub-folders as you said. But all the mails are unread in the sub-folders..

Comment: @i.h4d35 Information about read/unread messages and folder subscriptions is stored in the `configdirectory` defined in */etc/imapd.conf* (e.g. `/var/lib/cyrus/user/i/i.h4d35(.seen|.sub)`) which you would need to sync as well. All in all, Cyrus is cumbersome to handle in HA configurations - you might want to look at Dovecot, which has a number of supported and well-documented modes for operating multiple instances on shared storage or auto-replicating cluster filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

try `reconstruct -rf user.testuser`

It should give you an output like this:

```
discovered user.testuser.subfolder1
discovered user.testuser.subfolder2
discovered user.testuser.subfolder3
discovered user.testuser.subfolder4
```

Then check your frontend (Web UI or desktop client) and you may find the subfolders re-created

Comment: Note: whether a dot (`.`) or a slash (`/`) is used as a hierarchy separator is configurable in */etc/imapd.conf* through the `unixhierarchysep` configuration parameter. The default is indeed "no", so dots are used, but I have seen distros giving a sample config where it is set to "yes".